# login redirect to another app view

Tags: python, django, django-templates

This is my project structure

```
project
    app
    login
    manage.py
```

After successful login i want my user will be redirect to `localhost:8000/app` but currently it will redirect to `http://localhost.com:8000/accounts/login/?next=/` because i set it up my login view as

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.POST and form.is_valid():
        user = form.login(request)
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            return render_to_response('app/home.html',RequestContext)
        else:
            return HttpResponse('disabled account')
    return render_to_response('login.html', form ,RequestContext)
```

i can't able to use `HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app.views.dashboard'))` because dashboard view not exit in the same **login** `views.py`

if i import like

`from app import views as app_dashboard` or `from app import dashboard`

i am getting below error

> Reverse for 'app.views.dashboard' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

final note, below is my login url currently

```
<a href="{% url "django.contrib.auth.views.login" %}?next={{request.path}}" id="signIn">Sign in</a>
```

**Added:**

app/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('app.views',
    (r'^$', 'dashboard_view'),
```

project/urls.py

```
url(r"^", include("app.urls",)),
(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page' : '/accounts/login'}),
```

Comment: Please, show us your `urls.py` of `app_dashboard` application.

Comment: @goliney i added url.py .. let me know if u want any..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First point: use named urls, cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns - this should resolve your `reverse` problem.

Second point: you show the code for your own login view but your `url.py` and template's extract both refer to `django.contrib.auth.views.login`. Also, you specify a `next` param in your template's url, so `django.contrib.auth.views.login` do redirect you there, as explained in the FineManual(tm):

> If called via POST with user submitted credentials, it tries to log the user in. 
>   If login is successful, the view redirects to the URL specified in next.
>   (...)

Finally: you don't need to write you own view if all you want is to force the login view to always redirect to a same URL:

> (...) If next isn’t provided, it redirects to settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL (which defaults to /accounts/profile/). If login isn’t successful, it redisplays the login form.

IOW:

1. use named urls everywhere (name your own urls, and use urls names when calling `reverse` or the `{% url %}` templatetag)
2. get rid of the `next=...` in your templates
3. set your `settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` to your dashboard's url.

Comment: after giving `name` in  `app/urls.py` urls now `reverse` working,

Comment: and secondly thanks for your clarification I didn't know previously i used two login systems. One is default  `auth login` and my own `login_view`. after decided to use `auth login` and  put `redirect_url` in settings.py now successful login redirect to `app` working ..

Comment: so conclusion and i have doubt, if i don't need login_view function then how django to validate the form i wrote, Silly question but i expect your answer.

Comment: This is documented here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.login

Answer (score -2):

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.POST and form.is_valid():
        user = form.login(request)
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/app/')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('disabled account')
    return render_to_response('login.html', form ,RequestContext)
```

Change render response to redirect 
give your required url to redirect

Comment: Using hard-coded urls instead of using Django's `reverse` feature is hardly a good idea.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers he said when importing app dashboard view getting into some error. Without import another app view , how to reverse ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yes i like your way. but @deeban answer ok for me. but As you mention `hard-coded` url not good. But i can not use reverse function in my case there. BUt can you show some example how to give `namespace` url

Comment: I've never had *any* problem using `reverse` in any of my Django projects, and I've been using Django since the very first public release (0.9.something). wrt/ how to use named urls (and I was not necessarily talking about name*space*d urls), there's quite some doc on djangoproject.com so I don't see the need to rewrite it here. Start with the fine manual, and come back if/when you have questions.